# Isotope- works on jsFiddle but not on site

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry, jsfiddle

I began experimenting with Isotope on a jsFiddle that I stumbled across - then copied the exact code into text/edit to make a very basic test page. **Here's my problem: the jsFiddle and the test page I've made don't match.**

- jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/emilyryder/DEQZB/
- My test site: http://emilyryder.com/test/test.html

My desired affects are the masonry layout, three columns, and percentage widths so they re-size with the browser.

**My test page only seems to be obeying the CSS and not the JavaScript.**

I've used JavaScript but not jQuery, and I understand that Isotope is a jQuery plug-in. (Is there a step I'm missing here or is it right for me to just throw this code at my site?)

There's also a "External resource" which I now think is code for the original jsFiddle that I found, but at the time (about an hour ago) I thought that it was generated for me as I wrote script and that I was meant to attach it- it's saved as the same name of "jquery.isotope.min.js". (Never used jsFiddle before either haha) Removing the code link has no effect on the site, however.

jsFiddle Code in my test.html page requesting the JavaScript and CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="teststyle.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

your script tags are not closed properly

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="teststyle.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
```

leaving a `script` tag unclosed may prevent the next `script` from correctly included in the page

**In other words:** It is not [jsfiddle](/questions/tagged/jsfiddle) issue.

Comment: Hey thanks however I noticed that just a few minutes prior to you commenting actually! But it didn't change anything on the site :(

Comment: @EmilyRyder can you try the same setting as given in the sample http://plnkr.co/edit/xix4dTo9ar8zKZNOMNQH?p=preview

Comment: @EmilyRyder can you replicate the same code in your test page - maintain the same structure as files and styles

Answer (score 0):

you should attach jquery file and also a call back function you are missing both part

use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="teststyle.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.isotope.min.js">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var $container = $('#container');

$container.load(function () {
    $container.isotope({
        // options...
    });
});


$(function () {
    var $container = $('#container'),
        $items = $('.item');

    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 0
        },
        resizesContainer: false,
        getSortData: {
            fitOrder: function ($item) {
                var order,
                index = $item.index();

                if ($item.hasClass('large') && index % 2) {
                    order = index + 1.5;
                } else {
                    order = index;
                }
                return order;
            }
        },
        sortBy: 'fitOrder'
    });

    $items.click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // nothing to change if this already has large class
        if ($this.hasClass('large')) {
            return;
        }
        var $previousLargeItem = $items.filter('.large');

        $previousLargeItem.removeClass('large');
        $this.addClass('large');
        $container
        // update sort data on changed items
        .isotope('updateSortData', $this)
            .isotope('updateSortData', $previousLargeItem)
        // trigger layout and sort
        .isotope();
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I looked into callback functions and I don't need one. Also, the third script is the exact same as my "js.js" script. Finally, you included some other "ajax" jquery with code that looks like a scam. So I don't think so. Why are you telling me to do this?

Comment: I just tried calling the js.js file how you recommended but it looks the same. I do want to know why you are wanting me to call this "http://ajax.googleapis.com" code though

Comment: @EmilyRyder you have not included jQuery library, if you look at the console it is throwing an error, include the library before isotope library is included `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I understand now. Sorry for thinking it was a scam hushme haha. SO I ADDED THIS LIBRARY.... but now it's not loading at all. Here's a new link http://emilyryder.com/test/test2.html

Comment: @EmilyRyder it is working, but the elements are hidden because of some style related issues

Comment: @ArunPJohny I guess that leads us to my next question...how do you know it's style related and do you have suggestions? (btw you're so awesome for helping me with this haha)

Comment: @EmilyRyder probably you can have a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/xix4dTo9ar8zKZNOMNQH?p=preview

Comment: @ArunPJohny I guess I'm still having the same issue where I can see it in the editor but when I upload the files or view them in my browser they don't show up.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I mean- the images show up but the javascript still doesn't work.